# Write and read on a socket returns different byte count

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a client-server application that uses AF_UNIX sockets. 
The client generates a string and then sends it on the socket after it has sent an header. The server then reads the header, allocates space for the string and then reads the string.

The header is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long key;
    op_t op; // op_t is an enum
} header_t;
```

And the string is stored with its length:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int len;
    char* buf;
} data_t;
```

There's also another struct that groups these two things into one (not a choice of mine, I *have to* use these things as they are).

```
typedef struct {
    header_t hdr;
    data_t data;
} message_t;
```

I'm using `writev()` system call to send the data over the socket, this way:

```
int sendRequest(long fd, message_t *msg) {
    struct iovec to_send[3];
    /* Header */
    to_send[0].iov_base = &(msg->hdr);
    to_send[0].iov_len = sizeof(header_t);

    /* Data */
    to_send[1].iov_base = &(msg->data.len);
    to_send[1].iov_len = sizeof(msg->data.len);

    to_send[2].iov_base = msg->data.buf;
    to_send[2].iov_len = msg->data.len;

    int c;
    if((c = writev(fd, to_send, (msg->data.len > 0) ? 3 : 2)) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("#### %i BYTES WRITTEN (header: %i) ####\n",c, to_send[0].iov_len);

    return 0;
}
```

To read, I use two distinct functions, one to read the header, and one to read the data:

```
int readHeader(long fd, header_t *hdr) {
    struct iovec to_read[1];

    to_read[0].iov_base = hdr;
    to_read[0].iov_len = sizeof(header_t);

    errno = 0;
    int c;
    if((c = readv(fd, to_read, 1)) <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("[H] %i BYTES READ \n",c);

    return 0;
}

int readData(long fd, data_t *data) {
    struct iovec to_read[2];
    /* First, read how long is the buffer */
    to_read[0].iov_base = &(data->len);
    to_read[0].iov_len = sizeof(data->len);

    int c;
    if((errno = 0, c = readv(fd, to_read, 1)) <= 0)
        return -1;

    if(data->len > 0) {
        data->buf = calloc(data->len, sizeof(char));
        if(data->buf == NULL)
            return -1;
        /* Read the string */
        to_read[1].iov_base = data->buf;
        to_read[1].iov_len = data->len;

        if((errno = 0, c += readv(fd, &to_read[1], 1)) <= 0) {
            free(data->buf);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        data->buf = NULL;
    }
    printf("[D] %i BYTES READ (%i + %i)",c, to_read[0].iov_len, to_read[1].iov_len);

    return 0;
}
```

And here comes the problem.
If I send a string 8193 bytes long, everything works fine on the client, that outputs
`8213 bytes written (header: 16)` which is correct, because 16 bytes are from the header, 4 bytes are from the `len` field and 8193 are from the string.
But the server prints this:
`[H] 16 bytes read` (okay) and then `[D] 8176 bytes read` (wrong!). So, there are 21 bytes to read left. Why? If I try to send a string that has a length of 8192 or less, everything works fine. And assuming that there's a limit on the bytes that can be read by `readv()`, what is the correct way to read everything that was written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the server prints this: [H] 16 bytes read (okay) and then [D] 8176 bytes read (wrong!).

Surely it would be safer to say "unexpected" than "wrong".  It is safe to assume that `readv()` returns the number of bytes actually read, as it is specified to do.  You appear to have fallen into one of the classic traps of these POSIX low-level I/O functions: in any given call, they are not guaranteed to transfer the full number of bytes you request them to do.  This one reason why on success they return the number of bytes transferred.

> what is the correct way to read everything that was written?

I more often see people run into this with the `read()` and `write()` functions, but `readv()` and `writev()` work the same way except as necessary to spread input across multiple buffers or to gather output from multiple buffers, respectively.  With either set of functions, if you want to transfer a specific number of bytes then you must be prepared to perform multiple reads or writes in a loop, at each iteration picking up where the previous iteration left off.

It may at this point occur to you that transferring the full contents of your multiple, differently-sized buffers across multiple calls could get complicated fairly quickly (and if it hadn't before then it should do now).  The `readv()` and `writev()` functions are not really intended for the kind of use to which you are trying to put them.  They are barely any higher-level than `read()` and `write()` themselves, and they are best suited for treating multiple fixed-size buffers as a single, larger buffer.

For a case such as yours, I think it will be easier to use `read()` and `write()`.  You could consider writing helper functions that wrap those those to perform the needed looping to fully read a specified number of bytes; this will save you repeating such code for each separate data item you want to transfer.  Having written such functions, the main code will actually be simpler than what you have now, because you will not need to set up the iovectors.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the correct way to read everything that was written?

There is no guarantee that a readv will return all the data at once. If the first read does not return all the requested bytes than you need to call read/readv again to get the rest.